# Is it possible to compile and run local source code via ssh without copying the program to the remote machine?

Tags: ssh, remote

Suppose I have a Java project with a bunch of source codes in my local machine (any OS).

I want to compile and run the source code in a remote Linux machine via ssh without copying the source code into the machine.

How can I do that?

Comment: How about a sshfs mount of the remote and then run your local script against the mounted data. Does that work for your requirements?

Comment: You have to copy the source code there in some sense. I think you mean not permanently commit to local disk? You could create a working tmpfs then delete it when done.

Comment: @spinkus, the remote disk doesn't have sufficient space.

Comment: Tmpfs exists in RAM so may work well depending on how much RAM you have. If not a remote mount is best bet as  @Stephen said.

Comment: Export your PC data using CIFS/NFS or mount it using SSHFS.